# ip spoofing not working jmeter

Tags: jmeter, ip, spoofing

I am trying IP spoofing in JMeter HTTP requests but my public IP is going to the request, not the IP address which I have specified under advanced option in HTTP sampler. can anyone help me in this?

I am also sharing the screenshot of my test plan.

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYsFI.png)
In my test plan my let's say my IP is x.x.x.x and the IP which I have configured for IP spoofing is: 192.168.23.12 as shown in the screenshot but request to the server is still going with my IP which is x.x.x.x.

Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: It is working on my machine. Can you check if you have "Header manager" below your HTTP sampler?

Comment: hi sunny

yes i have header manager under my http sampler.

Comment: Check if the header manager is having some value that represents your public domain. Try without header manager and with header manager for comparison

Comment: no header manager does not contain any information regarding my public domain . i am attaching a screenshot here for your reference : https://tinypng.com/web/output/k5vzrw42kqnpnhakzay3j319r12xucy4/Screen%20Shot%202018-04-25%20at%2017.11.36.png

Comment: Type the following at the command line prompt to alias the new IP of 192.168.0.101 to your existing subnet mask
**sudo ifconfig en0 alias 192.168.0.101 255.255.255.0** If you want to get rid of the alias, just type:
**sudo ifconfig en0 -alias 192.168.0.101**...Then try

Comment: after running these commands i have tried and following error occured .

https://tinypng.com/web/output/5zm3eqvbc1rgvfff3zwrhb579b6nvyb5/Screen%20Shot%202018-04-25%20at%2017.47.12.png


https://tinypng.com/web/output/cc95k7tdgc22v55735kxdqwy95kgm0nx/Screen%20Shot%202018-04-25%20at%2017.48.37.png

Comment: How you are checking it..I hope using debug postprocessor or something. I tried the same and got this. **HTTPSampler.domain=192.168.12.12** (Public IP) ,**HTTPSampler.proxyHost=192.168.11.11** (Spoofed).

Comment: did you checked my screenshots ?? are u using the same configuration.?

Comment: i have also checked using debug postprocessor there it is showing the ip which i have set and when i captured the traffic using wireshark there it is showing different source ip address . screenshot for both is shown below.: 

https://tinypng.com/web/output/08grju9m6uvya3a8p4na2wz7jwzyawkq/Screen%20Shot%202018-04-25%20at%2018.07.42.png

https://tinypng.com/web/output/g31ra5azepra5rxdbte5get0ha6rvygc/Screen%20Shot%202018-04-25%20at%2018.07.35.png

Comment: I have pasted my test plan as an answer. Please check if it is what you are doing.

Comment: Are you using wireshark on browser or jmeter? If on browser it will show public IP but if you sniff jmeter then you get the spoofed ip. Dont mind, I am just trying to debug step by step from whatever I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler documentation

> Source address field **[Only for HTTP Request with HTTPClient implementation]**

So change "Implementation" to `HttpClient4` and it should start working as expected.

Also be aware that you need to have this IP address (or [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing)) defined in the underlying operating system.

See [Using IP Spoofing to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter) article for more information and configuration instructions for different operating systems.

Comment: HI DMITRI 

i have already seen that blog and i don't know how to add alias ip in mac system so can you please help me out in this?

Comment: One more thing when i try to use HTTPIMPLEMENTATION then error shows as : Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind .    something , can you please help me out for that too ? i have tried searching on internet too but didn't got any solution

Comment: Hi sunny it worked i just added the ip address as alias and it worked perfectly and even wireshark captured the source as the spoofed ip address but i have one question in . case i want to test it with hundereds or even thousands ip then do i have to add all of them as my alias?
or if there is any way to do so plz let me know. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below test plan:-

[image]

[image]

Comment: i am following the same steps and i'm using wireshark for capturing traffic for jmeter.