# JMeter - Set HTTP Source address (aka IP spoofing) isn't working

Tags: jmeter

I want to send HTTP request using different IP country,

I tried to assign Source address by IP, also with HTTPClient4, and it fails:

```
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:339)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.java:92)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$JMeterDefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HTTPHC4Impl.java:336)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:843)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:574)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1231)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1220)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I found previous post and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50017753/ip-spoofing-not-working-jmeter), but it seems irrelevant, because HttpClient4 isn't working

> So change "Implementation" to HttpClient4 and it should start working as expected.

I tried with Java implementation and although it didn't failed, it didn't updated the IP seen in server

I added in hosts file a line with the IP

```
1.33.213.199 localhost
```

Can I change my IP in HTTP Request using vanilla JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work, you're getting the error because the IP address (or at least an [IP alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing)) **must exist** on the system so Java (and JMeter) could use it as the source address for establishing a [Socket](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/SocketProgramming/SocketProgram.html) connection.

1. Open network connection properties

   [image]
2. Open IPv4 properties

   [image]
3. Click "Advanved" button

   [image]
4. Add IP address(es) you want to simulate

   [image]

More information: [Using IP Spoofing to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter/)